# Javascript disappears in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, hyperlink, xss, tawk.to

I'm using the Tawk.to plugin to add a live chat to my website, and want to let customers open the chat by clicking a text link. Tawk.to gave me this link but when I paste that into my Wordpress editor it disappears as soon as I save the page. I paste it in the text screen as well as by inserting it as a hyperlink on the visual editor screen.

This is the link: `<a href="javascript:void(Tawk_API.toggle())"> Click to Chat </a>`

This is what I completely have on the website:

```
<div class="text">
<div class="phone"><strong>Vragen?</strong> <i class="fa fa-comments"></i><a href="javascript:void(Tawk_API.toggle())"> Click to Chat </a></div>
```

Does anyone know why it disappears and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress's page / post editors won't let you put Javascript in pages or posts. Both editors (TinyMCE and Gutenberg) [strip it out](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/) before saving your data, as you have seen. This is to avoid [cross-site-scripting attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/). Because cybercreeps.

To use this tawk app in WordPress, [follow their installation instructions](https://help.tawk.to/article/wordpress). They provide a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/tawk/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already installed and using the plugin. In their documentation they say you can open the chatbox via the code I mentioned above. But as you say it's stripped out by Wordpress. Is there a workaround maybe?

Comment: I suspect the documentation telling you to use that HTML/Javascript combination does not apply to WordPress. Use their widget. Ask them to add a shortcode to the next version of the plugin.